# How to avoid overlap in the fractions of a table

Tags: arrays, fractions, overlap

Is there any proper way to avoid overlap in the fractions of a table (see the picture)
[image]

The source code is :

```
\[
\textbf{S} = 
\begin{Bmatrix}
0 \\
- g \rho \eta \partial_x Z + \dfrac{1}{2} g Z^2 \partial_x \rho \\
- g \rho \eta \partial_y Z + \dfrac{1}{2} g Z^2 \partial_y \rho \\
0
\end{Bmatrix}.
\]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The traditional way is to add space to the `\\` with an optional argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\textbf{S} = 
\begin{Bmatrix}
0 \\[2pt]
- g \rho \eta \partial_x Z + \dfrac{1}{2} g Z^2 \partial_x \rho \\[10pt]
- g \rho \eta \partial_y Z + \dfrac{1}{2} g Z^2 \partial_y \rho \\[6pt]
0
\end{Bmatrix}.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use stacks.

You can specify the baselineskip if you use a stack:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\begin{document}
\[
\setstackgap{L}{24pt}
\textbf{S} = 
\braceVectorstack{
0 \\
- g \rho \eta \partial_x Z + \dfrac{1}{2} g Z^2 \partial_x \rho \\
- g \rho \eta \partial_y Z + \dfrac{1}{2} g Z^2 \partial_y \rho \\
0
}.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Between the two methods, the first one is more affordable. Thanks to you !

Comment: @AmineHANINI But, but, there is a sale on `stackengine` this week: stack ONE, get ONE free!

Answer (score 2):

Another way uses the `cellspace` package, which enables you to define *minimal* vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in table columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or another letter if you load `siunitx`). For the matrix environments of `amsmath`, you just have to load the package with option `[math]`. This will save you the tedium of deciding which length  you'll have to add as an optional argument of `\\`.

In addition, I propose to use the medium-sized fractions from `nccmath` for the coefficients, as they look better than the display-sized in this context, from my point of view:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}

\begin{document}

\[
\textbf{S} =
\begin{Bmatrix}
0 \\
- g \rho \eta \partial_x Z + \dfrac{1}{2} g Z^2 \partial_x \rho \\
- g \rho \eta \partial_y Z + \dfrac{1}{2} g Z^2 \partial_y \rho \\
0
\end{Bmatrix}.
\]
\medskip

\[
\textbf{S} =
\begin{Bmatrix}
0 \\
- g \rho \eta \partial_x Z + \mfrac{1}{2} g Z^2 \partial_x \rho \\
- g \rho \eta \partial_y Z + \mfrac{1}{2} g Z^2 \partial_y \rho \\
0
\end{Bmatrix}.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \mathbf{S} = \begin{Bmatrix}
  0 \\
-g\rho\eta\partial_x Z + \dfrac{1}{2} g Z^2 \partial_x \rho \\[10pt]
-g\rho\eta\partial_y Z + \dfrac{1}{2} g Z^2 \partial_y \rho \\
0
\end{Bmatrix} 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `{BNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`, you have a key `cell-space-limits`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=2pt}

\begin{document}

\[
\textbf{S} = 
\begin{BNiceMatrix}
0 \\
- g \rho \eta \partial_x Z + \dfrac{1}{2} g Z^2 \partial_x \rho \\
- g \rho \eta \partial_y Z + \dfrac{1}{2} g Z^2 \partial_y \rho \\
0
\end{BNiceMatrix}.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]